# Expo router | Switch from tab navigation to Stack navigation adds space on top

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-router

I'm trying expo with expo-router for a project. When i switch from tab navigation to stack navigation, It creates a double header one is the tab header & stack screen header. I don't want to show tab header in stack screen

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3n9Lv.png)

Answer (score 0):

In your `_layout.tsx` file (where you declare your  component), simply add `headerShown : false` to the `screenOptions` **prop** of the Tab component.

Like so :

```
 <Tabs
    
      screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
        headerShown: false
      }) 
 />
```

Hope it helps.